# Read XML data and save them to mysql database in symfony 4

Tags: mysql, xml, symfony4

I have a simple XML file. I need to read the data and save them to mysql database table (1 or 2 tables). The file is like following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://">  
<myfile>  
<title><![CDATA[All data]]></title>
<stock>
   <name><![CDATA[my name]]></name>
   <qty><![CDATA[0]]></qty>
   <price><![CDATA[4.99]]></price>
   <image><![CDATA[http://fashiondropshippers.com/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_463.jpg]]></image>
</stock>
</myfile>
</rss>
```

I am trying to do that in Symfony 4 using crawler. my codes in my controller are following

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addContent(file_get_contents('http://localhost/XML/myxml.xml'));

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    var_dump($domElement->nodeValue);
}

return new JsonResponse($domElement->nodeValue);
```

It displays data with errors. Now I need to save those data in mysql database tables. Could you please tell me how to proceed further ? 
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't clearly understand: you need help with reading data or with saving to DB?

Comment: @Nikita Leshchev i can read the XML data and it can be displayed on the browser using var_dump. now i need to save those data into database tables. any hints ?

Comment: use Doctrine: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html Feel free to ask if you have any difficulties

Comment: @Nikita Leshchev i know how to create table using doctrine. But can you tell me how to save those XML data into database tables ? do i need mapping XML nodes and table columns ?

Comment: Ok. I'll write algorithm as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If you want to save data to DB you have to do the following:

1. Add Doctrine to your project: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine
2. Create an entity: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class
3. Make migrations: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-creating-the-database-tables-schema and execute them
4. Save your data to DB https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database